# How to refresh user control by opened window with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link button in a user control, when I am going to click link button one page will open in a new window.
When the opened window page is closed, the user control should be refreshed. The user control resides in one main aspx page.

How to achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: Does your user control reside in an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: yes..my usercontrol is reside in updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with simple javascript

```
__doPostBack('update_panel_id', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your user control resides in an update panel, you can call the [__doPostBack()](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2) method to perform a partial postback that will asynchronously refresh that panel.

From the `click` handler of the button that closes your popup window, you can do:

```
window.opener.__doPostBack("yourUpdatePanelClientId", "");
```

Comment: i am getting "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'window.opener' is null or not an object" in usercontol have link button,when i am click this link button then new winow page is opening..so in that case how can refresh usercontol when i am going to clode window

Comment: That would happen if the code is not running in your popup window. Did you add it to your main window instead?

Comment: i have achieved this by self.parent.location.reload();